# How does GCM locate a user phone

Tags: java, android, cloud, google-cloud-messaging

My question is how does the Google Cloud Messaging know where to send the message to? does it work by IP Address? Is there an interval that runs a function on the phone to send the current location or IP Address of the phone to the Google server? Does anyone know?

Answer (score 6):

Google doesn't need to know the IP address of your device. Instead, your device connects to Google, identifies itself using whatever protocol Google uses for authentication, and Google then uses that established connection to send notifications to your device.

When your phone changes from one IP address to another, it simply makes a new connection to Google, and Google then uses that new connection for your notifications. Google wouldn't even need to keep track of your IP address after you disconnect, since as soon as you disconnect (like on a public wifi system), somebody else might start using that same address.

Answer (score 2):

Here is the link which explains the working of GCM http://developer.android.com/guide/google/gcm/gcm.html

Comment: Specifically this: "It uses an existing connection for Google services."

Comment: I read through the doc a few times but i still didn't find what i'm looking for. Specifically i am asking when you use the API to send a message how does the Google Server know where the phone is? say if my phone IP address is 5.5.5.5 when i register the app with GCM then it changes to 6.6.6.6 how does it know which one to send it to?

Comment: I never read any GCM communication related to ip address. Whenever your application is registered for GCM service, the unique registration id is generated for your device, which is stored on google GCM server and same id we have to store on our third party server. whenever we request for functionality we have to send this id to google sever and then google server will forward your request to the device..

Comment: "It uses an existing connection for Google services." -- I think this means that your device "phones home" periodically (continuously?).

Comment: meaning it has a service that runs every so often to update the current IP Address of the phone?

Answer (score 0):

Every GCM client creates a unique device token that you need to send to GCM server for sending the push notifications to client.

Here you can find [link](http://www.sherif.mobi/2012/07/gcm-php-push-server.html) explaining the GCM.

Answer (score 0):

**GCM Works by Running a Service of its Own to handle Push Notifications.**
This service requests the Google Cloud Server (GCM) with your app token ID created by GCM for any pending notifications created by your app and sends the response back with all the notifications from your token id to your app, and this happens for the all the apps using GCM.
So, basically if you have 5 apps which have implemented GCM then their token IDs will be send together by this service and GCM will check if any notification is available for the sent token id's and send them as a response.
**Read this thread, this guy has explained it, and GCM is reliable for new app builds !!**

http://eladnava.com/google-cloud-messaging-extremely-unreliable/