# How the notification system of any messaging app works

Tags: java, mysql

I apologize for my English right away. My question is very simple: when I send a message to a person, how does that particular person receive the notification? I know there are many services that do this, but I would like to understand the process behind it. My theory is this: there is a trigger on the message table, as soon as a record is added to this table, the backend sends a notification to the person, but the thing I don't understand is how can I track the person, I don't believe via IP since it is unreliable. I really apologize for my ignorance and I hope you can help me.

Comment: A message app requires the user to "log in". There's a "user_id" even if you are not seeing it each time you start the app. Typically messages are not stored in a database table (though it can be the case) but on different persistence mechanisms such as a queue or distributed key-value store or tuple-store, etc. Some services write to these stores (when "sending" the message), and later other services read from these queues to forward the message to the receiver. The delay can be minimal (a few ms) or can be longer in case of a surge.

Comment: How do these services forward the message to the user? This I don't understand, how do I backend to send a msg to a certain device? Through the User's IP?

Comment: Messages are typically forwarded by UI polling. Stackoveflow.com (here) is a good example. The browser is periodically --  and behind the scenes -- asking the backend for updates; these updates can be of several natures, such as "reputation gain", "message notification", "new questions added", "comments added/updated/deleted", etc. A single polling call can retrieve all these updates at once from the backend.

Comment: But then it is not the back-end that sends the notification to the device, but it is the device that periodically queries the DB (obviously via the back-end) to understand if there are updates for the user?

Comment: There are many solutions on how to do the messaging. The model I described is the typical "pull" model where the device requests for updates. There's also the model of "push notifications" where the backend sends updates to the device. Both can be useful. Of course there's more than the IP in the routing (natting, symmetric keys, etc) that secure the transmission.

Comment: In the push notifications model, how does the back-end figure out who to send the notifications to, via the device IP?

Comment: Suffice to say that there are a lot of "networking appliances" between the backend server and the phone. For example load balancers, firewalls, ISP routers, ISP bridges, Mobile servie routers and bridges, etc. Each one converts the pair IP/port into something different. The backend sees the internal IP/port that lives in that segment. Each network appliance on each segment translates back and forth between those two ends. The IP/ports that live between them have no meaning outside each segment. You probaly want to learn about NAT and how this affects each network segment.

Comment: And then the backend how to identify the device?

Comment: You should look into [push-notifications](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/70250188/aapt2-aapt2-7-0-3-7396180-windows-daemon-android-studio-please-help-me) if you're making a messaging app with notifications. From ***my firebase cloud messaging service experience***, how a notification app may work is that each user gets their own token generated. The token is sent to the backend and that allows operations that notify the user by using that token to identify their device; in this case the "backend" pulls the users token when it detects a change in data and uses it to forward him updates.

Comment: For security reasons, I think, the tokens are consistently updated and resent to the server.

Comment: That is fine. Now a doubt arises about the use of this token: 1) inside that token automatically generated by Firebase, there is information to contact the device (For example IP, Access port for Firebase, MAC Address.)
2) In the background a socket is active that never dies, and therefore the back-end uses the token to identify the socket (i.e. the client) to which it will have to send the notification.

Is at least one of the doubts correct? Or I'm not understanding anything and I'd better go play Minecraft

Comment: 1) if you want to implement a messaging application, then forget mysql as your delivery mechanism as it does not have any notification functionality. You have to poll it regularly to pick changes up. 2) keeping tabs on connected vlients is messaging solution specific. You heed to pick one and understand how it works!

Comment: I am not using anything for the moment. I just wanted to understand what's behind a messaging app, like whatsapp. So there are mainly two types of models: Pull, it is the client that fetches updates through queries made continuously. Push, the server sends updates to the client over a connection that never dies. Right or am I doing something wrong?

Comment: The token is the id of the device, the work of finding your device is done by Google itself(based on a preexisting connection, which updates on reconnecting to Google) in the case I mentioned. Source: [How does google cloud messaging find your app](https://stackoverflow.com/a/12963909/16653700) - Greg Hewgill.

Comment: So every single time my Public IP Address is updated (Connection change, offline for a few seconds, etc ...) a background service contacts the google servers again to re-connect, in this way I am always traceable for notifies you. Quite right?

Comment: Essentially, that's correct.

Comment: Good. Are these kind of connections essentially sockets? Or has Google invented a new type of technology that is much more effective?

Comment: This is a guess(with some evidence and research): To connect to any website ips and sockets are used, but that isn't the only thing necessary for Google to send you a notification, it's probably primarly based on user data you share with Google. Once Google has identified your account then it'll go through the transfer protocols required to send you the notification.